# Error deploying Rails 5 app with Sinatra 2.0.0beta2 to Amazon Linux AMI

Tags: sinatra, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, ruby-on-rails-5, puma

I'm running into an exception with [Sinatra](https://github.com/sinatra/sinatra) 2.0.0 beta 2 with Rails 5 deploying to the Amazon Linux AMI v 2.1.6.  I've posted [the issue](https://github.com/sinatra/sinatra/issues/1176) in the Sinatra Github repro but it's been suggested I post it here.

Edit: I ran into this using Elastic Beanstalk but as @neal reports, this also happens with Capistrano deploying to EC2.

Steps to reproduce the issue follow:

1. Make a new Rails 5 application in a clean directory

   ```
   $ gem install rails
   $ rails --version
   (confirm Rails 5.0.0.1)
   $ rails new test-app
   ```

Add this line to the gemfile:

```
gem 'sinatra', '2.0.0.beta2'
```

2. Create a new  Elastic Beanstalk Web environment of type “64bit Amazon Linux 2016.03 v2.1.6 running Ruby 2.3 (Puma)”, Web server.  Use all defaults except change the instance size to t2.small (anything smaller doesn’t have enough memory to deploy)
3. Add two new environment variables to the Elastic Beanstalk environment using the Web console
   SECRET_KEY_BASE = (set a value for this)
   RAILS_ENV = production
4. Deploy the application to this new environment, for example with the eb command line tools.
5. Deploy it again
6. Tail the logs through the Elastic Beanstalk console

RESULT:

```
-------------------------------------
/var/log/puma/puma.log
-------------------------------------
=== puma startup: 2016-08-26 02:39:12 +0000 ===
=== puma startup: 2016-08-26 02:39:12 +0000 ===
[15926] - Worker 0 (pid: 15929) booted, phase: 0
[15926] - Gracefully shutting down workers...
/opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sinatra-2.0.0.beta2/lib/sinatra/main.rb:11:in `expand_path': No such file or directory - getcwd (Errno::ENOENT)
    from /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sinatra-2.0.0.beta2/lib/sinatra/main.rb:11:in `block in <class:Application>'
    from (eval):1:in `run?'
    from /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sinatra-2.0.0.beta2/lib/sinatra/main.rb:26:in `block in <module:Sinatra>'
    from /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/puma-3.6.0/lib/puma/cluster.rb:120:in `fork'
    from /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/puma-3.6.0/lib/puma/cluster.rb:120:in `block in spawn_workers'
    from /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/puma-3.6.0/lib/puma/cluster.rb:116:in `times'
    from /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/puma-3.6.0/lib/puma/cluster.rb:116:in `spawn_workers'
    from /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/puma-3.6.0/lib/puma/cluster.rb:426:in `run'
    from /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/puma-3.6.0/lib/puma/launcher.rb:172:in `run'
    from /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/puma-3.6.0/lib/puma/cli.rb:74:in `run'
    from /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/puma-3.6.0/bin/puma:10:in `<top (required)>'
    from /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/bin/puma:23:in `load'
    from /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/bin/puma:23:in `<top (required)>'
    from /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.1/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:63:in `load'
    from /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.1/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:63:in `kernel_load'
    from /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.1/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:24:in `run'
    from /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.1/lib/bundler/cli.rb:304:in `exec'
    from /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.1/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
    from /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.1/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
    from /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.1/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor.rb:359:in `dispatch'
    from /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.1/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/base.rb:440:in `start'
    from /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.1/lib/bundler/cli.rb:11:in `start'
    from /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.1/exe/bundle:27:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.1/lib/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:98:in `with_friendly_errors'
    from /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.1/exe/bundle:19:in `<top (required)>'
    from /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/bin/bundle:23:in `load'
    from /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>'
[15926] === puma shutdown: 2016-08-26 02:41:17 +0000 ===
[15926] - Goodbye!
=== puma startup: 2016-08-26 02:41:20 +0000 ===
=== puma startup: 2016-08-26 02:41:20 +0000 ===
[16296] - Worker 0 (pid: 16299) booted, phase: 0
```

Comment: Still present in the latest Amazon Linux AMI 2016.09 v2.2.0

Answer (score 0):

This isn't just an elastic bean stalk issue, I can confirm it also happens when deploying a rails 5 app using capistrano / EC2 Ubuntu / nginx

Comment: Thanks @neal, I edited the post to reflect this isn't specific to Elastic Beanstalk.  Would you mind upvoting this question?